# Haskell - Type error in application: Type does not match

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, hugs

I am getting a matching error:

> Expression     : parseExpr (append p e) es
>
> Term           : parseExpr
>
> Type           : Expr -> String
>
> Does not match : a -> b -> c

when I try executing this code in the marked line:

```
data Expr = Atom String | Var String | Pred String [Expr] | Expr String

append :: String -> String -> String
append a b = a++b

parseExpr :: Expr -> String
parseExpr (Atom a) = a
parseExpr (Var x) = x
parseExpr (Pred p (e:es)) = parseExpr (append p e) es -- ERROR HERE
```

Although e is always going to be a String from the Expr object definition that I stated above. Is there a way to state this?

Comment: The error message seems clear enough to me. `parseExpr` is of type `Expr -> String`, but you're calling it with two arguments.

Comment: in `parseExpr (Pred p (e:es)) = ...` `p` will be a `String`, `e` will be an `Expr` and `es` will be a `[Expr]`. Why do you think `e` will be a `String`?

Comment: @user5402 Because Expr can always be broken down into a String I guess? Isn't that correct? I'm trying to perform a toString for Expr.

Comment: still, `parseExpr` takes just one argument. But in `parseExpr (append p e) es` you call it with 2 arguments. That's not going to work...

Comment: @Michael is there a different way to type cast Expr to a String?

Comment: @SalmaFG Can you add to your question what you are trying to do? Possible a sample input and output will help the readers of this question.

Comment: Please install `ghc` and uninstall `hugs` forever.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your confusion is here:

```
data Expr = ... | Expr String
```

This does not mean that every `Expr` can be converted to a string. It just means that there is a function called `Expr` which takes a `String` and returns an `Expr` (the type).

The obvious way to define `parseExpr` for the `Pred` case is to call `parseExpr` on the elements of the `Expr` list, e.g.:

```
parseExpr (Pred p exprs) = 
    let strs = map parseExpr exprs  -- this is a [String]
        s    = concat strs          -- this is a String
    in p ++ s
```

Perhaps you want `s = intercalate " " strs` to join together the strings with spaces? A concrete example would be helpful.